# bootstrap Grid alignment issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

i expect bootstrap Grid like this. [image]

But i have this output [image]

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: peru">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background-color: yellowgreen; text-align: right;">a</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8" style="background-color: red; text-align: right">b</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to remove offset from second div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove offset from second div.

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: peru">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background-color: yellowgreen; text-align: right;">a</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red; text-align: right">b</div>
</div>
```

Offset creates negative space from left & defining 8 col space from left forces the div to fall off the flow.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMY36/101/)

Answer (score 1):

Move columns to the right using `.col-md-offset-*` classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by `*` columns. For example, `.col-md-offset-4` moves `.col-md-4` over four columns

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: peru">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="background-color: yellowgreen; text-align: right;">a</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red; text-align: right">b</div>
    </div>
```

**Reason Points**

1. bootstrap divides the one horizontal row with 12 columns width
2. offset means leaving the left margin space by columns
3. According to your point first div is `offset=4` and `length = 4` `total = 8` columns and remaining columns are 4 only out of 12
4. second div holds `offset = 8` `length=4` `total = 12` but it has to be just `4` column in length
5. as the left space is just 4 columns you are giving extra 8 columns so it shifted to new row there it leaves `col-md-offset-8` this leaves 8 column left margin and the remaining 4 columns are occupied in second row.

for more information [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the applause @GeethWelagedara